# How to count and group items by day of the week?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following (MySQL) table called "tweets":

```
tweet_id   created_at
---------------------
1          1298027046
2          1298027100
5          1298477008
```

I want MySQL returning the number of tweets per day of the week; taking the above data it should return:

```
Wednesday 1
Friday    2
```

I now have the following query (which should return the day of the week index, not the full name):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(`tweet_id`),
  WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))
FROM tweets2 
ORDER BY WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))
```

This however returns:

```
COUNT(`tweet_id`)   WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))
7377                4
```

(There are a total of 7377 tweets in the database). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use the DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)) function instead of WeekDay (FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)) function and group by created_at

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(`tweet_id`),
DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) AS Day_Name1
FROM tweets2 

GROUP BY Day_Name1
ORDER BY Day_Name1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a count, but you don't have a group by. You should include a

```
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not grouping by week day so you only get one grand total. Try this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(`tweet_id`),
  WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))
FROM tweets2 
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))
ORDER BY WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`));
```